# How to transform this into Boyce-Codd Normal Form?

Tags: database, relational-database, database-schema, database-normalization

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. This is what I am being asked:

```
Normalize the following schema into BNCF:
T ((A, B), C, E, F, G)

The functional dependencies besides the key are:
A, B → C, E
F, B, A → G
B → B
F, C → C, G, E
C, F → E
E → G, E
```

So, I came up with this:

```
T ((A, B), C, E, F)
X((A,B), C, E)
W ((F,B,A), G)
Q ((B))
L ((F,C), G, E)
J ((C,F), E)
R ((E),G)
```

But it gives me this error:

> Result is not as expected. Modify your input and try again.

And I have no clue where the error is. Can someone explain to me what I should do?

Comment: Why you write: `((A, B), C, E, F, G)` and not `(A, B, C, E, F, G)` ? Has the couple of attributes A, B some special meaning? (It cannot be the key, given the functional dependencies that you have specified).

Comment: That is not something I wrote. That is given..

Comment: The brackets in the attribute list are used to denote the primary key for the table.

Comment: @philipxy since AB+ is ABCEG. F is missing, so the (unique) candidate key is ABF.

Comment: @Renzo But you were *told* AB is a CK. It doesn't need to follow from the other FDs, they are "besides" the CK.

Comment: @philipxy, I think you are correct. I had the impression the the question was without much sense, if AB is a CK, given the explicit mention of AB in a FD without all the attributes on the right part.

Comment: If you want to know why the error message then read and act on [mcve]. If you want feedback on your solution then give the algorithm you are following & what choices you made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the nested parentheses indicate a CK (candidate key) then

`A, B → C, E` is implied by the CK
`F, B, A → G` ditto
`B → B` is trivial
`F, C → C, G, E` is implied by `F, C → G, E`
`C, F → E` is redundant given `F, C → G, E`
`E → G, E` means `F, C → G, E` is implied by `F, C → E`

{A, B} being a CK means `A, B → C, E, F, G`, plus we have `F, C → E` and `E → G`. We can use a BCNF algorithm to get a decomposition comprising ((A, B), C, F) plus your J ((C,F), E) and R ((E), G).

You don't explain your solution (what BCNF algorithm you are using and what choices you made). But note that the FDs that hold in a relation are all the ones generated by Armstrong's axioms when some explicitly given ones hold. (Including the ones that hold because we were told a CK.) Also note that in one BCNF algorithm when we pick some FD (functional dependency) X → Y that holds in schema R that violates BCNF we replace R by schemas X+ and R - (X+ - X); and the set of FDs used is the closure of the explicitly given ones.

Comment: Thanks mate, I just needed an explanation! Appreciate it.